# Cannot connect to network drive

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

I have created a partition on my hardrive on a macbook (OS Sierra), but cannot connect it to a network drive. I have checked across my team, and they seem to have no problem plugging into it.

Everytime I hit `Ctrl + K` and try to connect, I get the message :

> There was a problem connecting to the server "xxxxx". The server may
>   not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the serve name of
>   IP address, check your network connection and then try again.

I will appreciate any pointers in solving this.

Here is what I am using to connect to the remote server:

```
smb://xxxxxxx.com/work/Repository/XXXXXXX
```

Comment: If it's a local partition why are you trying to connect to it over the network?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. Its to connect to my work's git repository and I would like to be able to connect it to this. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: The Ctrl K is to "connect to server" which implies a remote server/machine. So are you trying to connect to a partition located on a remote machine? Have you tried using its IP address? Can you provide example of what you put in the "connect to server" line? You can omit the private details, but maybe an example like smb://myserver.com/sharename ? (or if you don't use smb, what do you use?)

Comment: It sounds like the fact you created a new partition is irrelevant to your attempt to connect to a network share...

Comment: Will update question @Tetsujin. Not done this before but the gist is to connect to the remote server, I had assumed I needed to partition

Comment: @Darius updated my question

Comment: @Data_Kid Have you asked your colleagues how they connect to the git server? Is it a shared folder on a remote server? Is it a URL? Or they simply use the `git` command line (without the need to connect to server)?

Comment: They mostly use Windows PCs so they use `Net Use X // then the file location` @Darius

Comment: Check Daruis's comment first, but have you tested  or `smb//[ip address]/work/repo...` or `cifs://[ip address]/work/repo...`

Comment: @Tetsujin do not have the IP address but will give it a go. Could it be some setting on my mac preventing me for accessing it?

Comment: @Data_Kid Try doing an `nslookup xxxxx.com` and see if it resolves. If it does not resolve, ask your colleagues (or use their machine) and see if it resolves to an IP, and see if you can connect to it using the IP address - and also you might need to check why it resolve on theirs and not on yours (DNS issue)

Comment: I think it might be a DNS issue as even trying to nslookup the domain on its own is not resolving . But it works for google.com..any ideas to why this is happening?@Darius

Comment: @Data_Kid Is it a local server? Or it is an actual URL that should resolve? What DNS server do you use on your mac - and compare that to what DNS server they are using? Maybe they are using the DHCP set local server DNS hence why the domain resolves for them, and you happen to use google DNS (or other DNS server that is different to theirs)? Check and match the DNS, if that is a no-go (if they also use google dns or other common one), then use the IP and go from there.

Comment: @Darius first up thank you for the extended help. I have tried to ping the web address without the root paths ie `www.xxxx.com`. This has returned an IP address. When I try to use the IP address with the paths, it throws the same error again

Comment: @Data_Kid Can you even connect to that server at all using SMB? Using ctrl k and just put smb://www.xxxx.com - if this server truly have SMB (or cifs as per Tetsujin's idea) - then this will work, and prompt you for the username and password, and then give you choices of folders for you to connect to. If not, then maybe this is just a web address (http/https based git repository)?

Comment: Did you test with `cifs://xxxxxxx.com/work/Repository/XXXXXXX` already and what were those results? Can you ping or access the `xxxxxxx.com` server otherwise? What is the IP of your machine, what is the IP of the `xxxxxxx.com` server? Have you asked the server admin or network support if applicable? Can you confirm with 100% certainty the exact configuration with such a system that is connected for those you have checked with to confirm there's not anything simple you are missing. Perhaps you need to save a credential and then connect to the protocol path afterwards.... Ideas @Data_Kid